# Unsure about recursive sorting function?

Tags: f#

I would just like to understand what is happening in this function, particularly the third case. Thanks!

```
  let rec sort = function
  | []         -> []
  | [x]        -> [x]
 //need help understanding line below
  | x1::x2::xs -> if x1 <= x2 then x1 :: sort (x2::xs)
                                  else x2 :: sort (x1::xs)
```

Comment: The complication here may be caused by the fact that it doesn't correctly sorry all inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::` operator in F# is a list operator that generally looks like:

```
head :: rest
```

Here, `head` is the first item of a list, and `rest` is the rest of the list. I.e.,

```
let rest = [2; 3; 4]
let head = 1
head :: rest  // Has the value [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Note the different types: `head` is a *single item*, and `rest` is a *list of items*.

Now, the `::` operator can be used in pattern matching *or* as an operator to actually build a list. It has the same meaning either way, but in pattern matching, you're just saying "match **if** the list has this shape", whereas outside of pattern-matching syntax, you're saying "**make** the list have this shape". So in pattern matching, you'd have:

```
let describe lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> "Empty list"
    | head::rest -> sprintf "Head is %A and rest is %A" head rest
describe [1; 2; 3; 4]
// Result: "Head is 1 and rest is [2; 3; 4]"
```

Note that a list of just one item is perfectly valid to match against the `head::rest` pattern, in which case `rest` will just be an empty list:

```
let describe lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> "Empty list"
    | head::rest -> sprintf "Head is %A and rest is %A" head rest
describe [1]
// Result: "Head is 1 and rest is []"
```

The `::` operator can also be applied multiple times:

```
let describe lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> "Empty list"
    | [x] -> sprintf "List of just one item, %A" x
    | first::second::rest -> sprintf "First item is %A and second item is %A and rest is %A" first second rest
describe [1; 2; 3; 4]
// Result: "First item is 1 and second item is 2 and rest is [3; 4]"
```

Note how I added a case for a list of one item there? That's because if you match a list against the shape `first::second::rest`, it will *only* match if the list has at least two items. A list of just one item would put nothing into `second`, and thus wouldn't match. If I had left out the `[x]` pattern in this latest example, the compiler would have warned me that my match expression was incomplete.

So now we can see what that last line of your `match` expression is doing:

```
| x1::x2::xs -> if x1 <= x2 then x1 :: sort (x2::xs)
                            else x2 :: sort (x1::xs)
```

The pattern is saying "Match if this list has at least two items in it. Call the first item `x1`, then call the second item `x2`, then call the rest of the list `xs`." Then it compares the list's first and second items. The smaller of the two is taken as the first item of the function's output, and the "rest" of the function's output is "take the larger item, prepend it to the `xs` list, and then pass that through the `sort` function".

And by the way, can you spot the bug in this function? If not, consider what it will do with the following list:

```
[3; 4; 2; 1]
```

What will the output of this `sort` function be with that input?

Comment: Wow, that is a great explanation! Thank you so much! And, the output will be 3,2,1,4 and I now understand why.  Again, than you for all your help!